# How to vertical align middle a button in a dynamic div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to center a vertically aligned button in a div using bootstrap

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button class="btn" style="color: #660066;">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" data-ng-click="onClickBack()" ></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <h4> {{rootNode.nodeName}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see, I have two columns,one containing a button in the left, another containing Label. When label.length is increased then the div'll change the height -> I want the button to be always centered in the div.

Comment: Did you try using the offset-md-x classes?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`:

```
.col-xs-2, .col-xs-10 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
.col-xs-10 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/k4bpm/2/)**.

Though you will have to make sure to remove the white space in between the column `<div>`s in your markup. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/2049063) for more information on that.

Answer (score 7):

I used this. Check the "style property". That will do the trick.

```
style='position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;margin-right: -50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%)'>

<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning'>
</span> Loading...</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the padding on the `H4` is more than the button. You can wrap you button inside the `H4` (perhaps not the best practice), or change the button padding in your CSS..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <h4>
    <button class="btn" style="color: #660066;">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" data-ng-click="onClickBack()"></i>
    </button>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <h4> {{rootNode.nodeName}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR, leave the button as is, and apply this CSS to the `H4`..

```
h4 {
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

### http://bootply.com/106259