# Vertically align button in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center my button vertically, but isn't working:

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-small btn-gray" ui-sref="login">Start Session</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.btn {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How to vertical align middle a button in a dynamic div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649296/how-to-vertical-align-middle-a-button-in-a-dynamic-div)

But, I think you need to just add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to your .btn CSS.